# Android reading file from memory card limits to 10kb on samsung phones

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to read contents from a file stored on the sdcard on an android phone. For this I use the following code:

```
public String readIt(File file) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), encoding));
        String line;
        while (( line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + '\n');
        }
        reader = null;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "File not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error reading file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This has been bothering me for a while, any idea of why it cuts of on samsung phones? And does anyone have a suggestion of how to solve it and also keeping the file encoding when reading it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
          FileReader fstream;
      try {
              fstream = new FileReader(filename);
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
              Log.e("meminfo", "File access error " + filename);
              return null;
      }

      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fstream, CHARS_TO_BUFFER);
```

using this snippet I have no problems on samsung phones.